# How to create a link in an iif condition in reporting services

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I want to create a link in a condition in reporting services.
i have something like

```
iif(SomeField = "Canceled",SomeFiled,SomeField & link)
```

So the output would be:

> Completed
>   Download Report (with link
>   to report)

But if i put html code like:

```
<a href="somelink">Somelink</a>
```

It just spits out the html code, and no link is created.

So, how do i make a link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to create a hyperlink in Reporting Services that opens in a new window 
I was at a client and the question came up "Can I jump to another web based tool from my report?".   The answer seemed obvious ... YES.   What was not straightfoward was how to open the other web based tool in another window.   Here is a solution a found (someone else's idea) that helped.

When designing the report:

Open up a text box properties window 
Go to Navigation 
Enable Jump to URL 
In the URL enter javascript:void(window.open( 'http://www.microsoft.com', '_blank')

Mike brown's blog not mine.

Answer (score 2):

The text box has properties that can be used to control this (called different things in each version).

Anyhow, the URL etc are properties that can be an expression that takes IIF.

- [SSRS 2008 "Go to URL"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188486.aspx)
- [SSRS 2005 "Jump to URL"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188486(SQL.90).aspx)
- [SSRS 2000 "Jump to URL"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa237964(SQL.80).aspx):

You should be able to make it open in a new window: I've done it before but can't look at what I did just now.